SSLCommerze payment method not showing on WooCommerce Checkout Page
I've installed a WooCommerce theme and set up SSLCommerz for payment processing in sandbox mode for testing purposes. Although SSLCommerz is enabled in the settings, the payment option is not showing at checkout. I’ve tried different plugin versions, including the latest one (version 6.0), but the problem persists.


The payment gateway that you are using is not compatible with new checkout Blocks, so if you want to use this payment gateway, you need to switch back to Classic checkout shortcode

Go to the Checkout Pages in WordPress, remove everything,
and add only this shortcode:
plaintext
[woocommerce_checkout]
This will ensure the WooCommerce checkout page works correctly.

The question asked why payment methods weren't showing on the checkout page, but the provided shortcode for the checkout page wasn't relevant to the issue.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
